# Which other texts apart from Shri Bhagvad Gita talk about the indestructible nature of human soul/atman?

Tags: puranas, vaishnavism, upanishads, atma, shaivism

I was wondering that Hinduism had so many different sects for different deities, was this belief of the soul being indestructible followed by Vaishnavism? also lord Shiva has been called the destroyer in many stories and texts , could he destroy human soul or atman?

Comment: Atma is the crucial tag for this Q. So, in order to add it I have to remove the Veda tag, which is not particularly relevant here. We can not add more than 5 tags. BTW welcome to the site :)

Comment: @Rickross thanks

Comment: @Rickross pls answer the question

Comment: I don't know the answer right now .. nothing coming to my mind .. but why did you delete your account? If you are reading my comment then please come back with another account.